# Segmentation fault c++ recursive function pointer

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault

I have a problem with one recursive function and its not about pointer because I tried without using pointer and I still got this error 
this is the compiler error:

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000402105 in 
neighbour (arr=0x62fbd0, i=0, j=4, r=false, l=true, u=true, b=false, number=2) at main.cpp:151
151         
neighbour(arr, i, j - 2, right(arr, i, j - 2), left(arr, i, j - 2), up(arr, i, j - 2), bottom(arr, i, j - 2), number);
```

and my function code is:

```
void neighbour(int *arr, int i, int j, bool r, bool l, bool u, bool b, int number)
{
    if (!(r || l || b || u))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (r)
    {
        *((arr + i * Size) + j + 2) = number;
        neighbour(arr, i, j + 2, right(arr, i, j + 2), left(arr, i, j + 2), up(arr, i, j + 2), bottom(arr, i, j + 2), number);
    }
    if (l)
    {
        *((arr + i * Size) + j - 2) = number;
        neighbour(arr, i, j - 2, right(arr, i, j - 2), left(arr, i, j - 2), up(arr, i, j - 2), bottom(arr, i, j - 2), number);
    }
    if (u)
    {
        *((arr + (i + 2) * Size) + j) = number;
        neighbour(arr, i + 2, j, right(arr, i + 2, j), left(arr, i + 2, j), up(arr, i + 2, j), bottom(arr, i + 2, j), number);
    }
    if (b)
    {
        *((arr + (i - 2) * Size) + j) = number;
        neighbour(arr, i - 2, j, right(arr, i - 2, j), left(arr, i - 2, j), up(arr, i - 2, j), bottom(arr, i - 2, j), number);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"this is the compiler error"* - Just fyi, that's not a compiler error. that's a *runtime* error.  That said, we need a [mcve] or all you're going to get are wild guesses.

Comment: how did you do it without the pointer?

Comment: @KamilCuk Not sure about more readable, but it's definitely less compilable.

Comment: Most likely, you are accessing `arr` out of bounds. There's no bounds checking in the code shown.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you are protecting the function from accessing values that are out of bounds. For example: `if (l) {... etc` assigns a value 2 left of `arr[i*Size+j]` if the value of i and j is 0, then this will seg fault. Try something like `if ( l && j >= 2) {... etc`

Comment: I'm protecting function from accessing out of bound members in right,left,up,bottom functions its not the problem

Comment: @ArefAzizian can you share the code for right,left .. as well?